# Mongodb slow query profiling output

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to understand the reason of slow queries in mongodb and following is the output. Could someone please let me know by looking at following output why is it really taking 23 seconds for the query? I do see locks fo read is 35seconds approximately. Is this time for holding the lock to read? If so why is it holding for such a long time?

```js
{ 
    "$query": { 
        "level": { "$in": [ 1 ] }, 
        "p_id": "7yhhh", 
        "is_new": false, 
        "ps.id": "569009", 
        "ps.namespace": "test", 
        "state": 1, 
        "created": { "$lte": new Date(1423504969640) } 
     }, 
     "orderby": { "created": -1 } 
 }
 ntoreturn:5 
 ntoskip:0 
 nscanned:514495 
 scanAndOrder:1  
 keyUpdates:0 
 numYields: 835 locks(micros) 
 r:35885043 
 nreturned:2 
 reslen:1005 
 23218ms
```

Comment: There seems to be a lack of indexes in general by the `nscanned` result. You can run your query with `.explain()` to show more detail of the indexes selected if any. But basically the most optimal thing will be to at least index the field that is going to reduce the results the most. Then possibly more.

Comment: Sure will check indexing. Also, with "locks(micros)r" being more is there any performance issue.What does this signify?

Comment: In short, lots of reading. Mostly it is the `nscanned` that is the concern since you are not actually returning many results from the query. You want the "scanned to returned" ratio to be a close to `1:1` as possible for best performance. Edit with the full "explain" output.

Comment: Thanks will cehck and update you.